# Faces suddenly missing

Tags: mesh, faces

I was working on something in Blender and when I loaded it up I noticed some faces missing. Thought the best way to fix it'll be filling it in. Problem is that some faces still stay transparent. They don't even show up on my texture area. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Could they have been hidden? try to un-hide all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to comment without seeing the blend file, however, you can try:

- Un-hiding all faces (`Alt + H`); and/or
- The `Make Normals Consistent` commend. Highlight all faces (using `A` in face mode), and then access the command by hitting space bar and searching for it.

I would also run the `Remove Doubles` command, just to make sure you have not created a face on top of another face when trying to "fill in" the gaps.

Comment: Oh thanks that,  Make Normals Consistent, worked. That only effects the faces right? I just wanted to make sure. It's my first time making Sim mods and I just wanted to make sure I didn't have to clean up anything like the rig for example.

Comment: I don't use rigs really, but if you are referring to Make Normals Consistent - yes it will only affect faces. If this solved your problem, I imagine your missing faces when you opened up the file weren't missing at all, but rather were flipped around the wrong way so they looked like they were. Make Normals Consistent does exactly what it sounds like - flips all faces the same way. Usually that's the way you want but, if not, highlight all again and use the Flip Normals command.